# How to change values in lower triangular of matrix in julia and transform to upper triangular?

Tags: julia

How to change values in lower triangular of matrix in julia and transform to upper triangular? I need help with homework

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for here.

Comment: Do you want a transpose of the matrix?

Comment: How to tril of matrix become triu of matrix and change the values of tril.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `LowerTriangular(A)' + A - UpperTriangular(A)` ?

Comment: i want to upper triangular values become all 3 example.

Comment: `for k in 1:size(A,1)
    A[diagind(A,k)] .= 3
end` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's still not 100% clear from your discussion in the comments above what you're looking for, but here's an attempt at answering:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

I'll go based on your first comment, indicating you want "`tril` of the matrix to become `triu` of the matrix and change values of `tril`".

As Stefan suggests in his comment, moving the lower triangular values of the matrix to the upper triangular can be accomplished by simply transposing the matrix:

```
julia> tril(A)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0
 4  5  0
 7  8  9

julia> triu(A)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 0  5  6
 0  0  9

julia> A_tr = A'
3×3 Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9
```

As you see, `A_tr` has the values returned by `tril(A)` in its upper triangular. You can then use @crstnbr's suggestion to replace all the lower triangular values with -3 (adding the minus to make the result visually clearer):

```
julia> for k in 1:size(A_tr, 1) A_tr[diagind(A_tr, k)] .= -3 end

julia> A_tr
3×3 Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 1  -3  -3
 2   5  -3
 3   6   9
```